# Where should I put the `include` statement?

Tags: ruby, module

I'm trying to use a module as a namespace for my constants. Let's say I have a module like this:

```
module AnimalModule
  Dog = 1
end
```

and a class called `PetStore` that uses the module. Where should I place the `include` statement?

(1) Is it like this:

```
# PetStore.rb
include AnimalModule
class PetStore
end
```

(2) or like this:

```
# PetStore.rb
class PetStore
  include AnimalModule
end
```

I try to use the the constant in my class's instance method, and both way seem to work the same:

```
class PetStore
  def feed
    puts Dog
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second style is the right choice. The difference is the scope of `Dog`. The first one includes the module in a larger scope. So it works in your example too. But it will not provide the namespace you want.

```
module AnimalModule
  Dog = 1
end
class PetStore
  include AnimalModule
end
Dog # => NameError: uninitialized constant Dog
PetStore::Dog # => 1

include AnimalModule
Dog # => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You include modules after the class just like you did in your second block of code:

```
C:\Users\Hunter>irb
irb(main):001:0> module AnimalModule
irb(main):002:1>   Dog = 1
irb(main):003:1> end
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> class PetStore
irb(main):005:1>   include AnimalModule
irb(main):006:1>   def feed
irb(main):007:2>     puts Dog
irb(main):008:2>   end
irb(main):009:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> p = PetStore.new()
=> #<PetStore:0x25e07b0>
irb(main):011:0> p.feed
1
=> nil
```

I used your code in the interactive interpreter and got `1` as the result of calling the `feed()` method.